# Error when creating a search bar: Initializer for conditional binding must have Option type, not 'String'

Tags: swift, xcode, search, option-type

I am trying to create a search bar within a TableView. I was able to get the search bar into the UI but I am struggling with the search functionality logic. I have been following a tutorial, but I still get an error in the code.

All the data is reading correctly through a json file.'

I receive an error in the 'filterContent(for: )' function. The error reads that "Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'String'"

Here is the relevant code within my TableView class. (Note the line with the error marked with a comment).

```
import UIKit

class LocationTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var locations = [Location]()

    var searchController:UISearchController!
    var searchResults = [Location]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false

    }

    func filterContent(for searchText: String) {

        searchResults = locations.filter({ (location) -> Bool in
            // The following line receives the error
            if let name = location.name {
                let isMatch = name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
                return isMatch

            }

            return false

            })

    }


    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchText = searchController.searchBar.text {
            filterContent(for: searchText)
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that:

```
location.name
```

is not an optional, but you are using conditional (let) syntax.
That only works for optionals, and location.name is not an optional.

If you change this:

```
if let name = location.name {
            let isMatch = name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
            return isMatch
        }
        return false
```

to this:

```
       let name = location.name
       let isMatch = name.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText)
       return isMatch
```

it will compile properly. No need for "return false"

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should have mentioned that I already attempted this. The app builds, however, it crashes when opening the app. The log reads 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value.'